# download the int input to array until is not smaller than previous one except first

Tags: python

download the int input to array until is not smaller than previous one
except first, I'm trying this way.

So this would look like this:

> 4, 1, 2, 1 and now break

I have no clue what to do, I've tryed many ways like double for loop but no one of them work

```
def make_list(size: int):
    return [int(input("enter element of the array:\n")) for _ in range(0, size)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 5
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: The main question is at title. The code should download the int input untill value given by input will be smaller than previous one. I have no clue what to really do after this

Comment: The title is a statement, not a question. You are not downloading anything in the code you show here. I think you are just using the word "download" incorrectly, so I can get past that. More importantly, you don't describe what problem you encountered or what your actual question is. I am glad to help, but we need more information, such as what happens when you run your code and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: With that said, your current code doesn't do anything because you don't call the function. I suggest you read more about functions and how to use them properly. The second thing I see is that you are trying to do too much in a single line with a list comprehension. While these are great tools, you probably need a for loop to accomplish your task instead. Also, for loops are much easier to debug because there are many smaller discrete steps that you can check instead of one huge step.

Answer (score 1):

so not sure if I understood the question (not very good at english), but I tried a little something that seems to give the output you wanted. Not very clean at the moment, so might update later.

```
def make_list(size: int):
    if(size > 0):
        tab = []
        firstNb = get_input()
        tab.append(firstNb)
        if(size > 1):
            lastNb = get_input()
            tab.append(lastNb)
            for _ in range(0, size - 1):
                nb = get_input()
                tab.append(nb)
                if(nb < lastNb):
                    return tab
                lastNb = nb
        return tab
    else:
        return []

def get_input():
    return int(input("enter element of the array:\n"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 5
    result = make_list(size)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that, maybe not in pretty way ( somethign does not work with list comprehension)

```
def create_array(size: int) -> [int]:
    x = [(int(input("enter element of the array:\n")))]
    # return ["break" if x[i] < x[i - 1] else int(input("enter element of the array:\n")) for i in range(0, size)]  somethign wrong there
    for i in range(0, size):
        x.append(int(input("enter element of the array:\n")))
        if x[i + 1 ] < x[i - 1]:
            return x
    return x
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        size = 5
        print(create_array(size))
```